# Post on Facebook Group wall as an App (not as User)

Tags: facebook, feed, facebook-group

Using the facebook API, is it possible to post on a closed group wall (specifically a group - not a fan page or anything similar), and have the wall post be created by / identified by the App and not associated with any user?  I am an admin of the closed group on facebook.

I have a running service that monitors an email inbox.  I would like to automatically create a wall post on the facebook closed group whenever an email is received.  I don't want to tie this action to any facebook users since the email  that is received isn't necessarily tied to any facebook users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems this isn't possible for the time being since facebook provide an appropriate permission.  There is a manage_pages permission but not a manage_groups permissoin